# Test Output not created for a selenium TestNG program

Tags: java, testng

I am facing this error

```
[Utils] Problem creating output directory C:\test-output\old\Default suite 
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\test-output\old\Default suite\toc.html 
[Utils] Directory C:\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
```

when I run the program. I have 2 projects and test output is successfully created under other project.

The only difference between them is that the one which works has the class under **"default package"(no src)** and the one which does not work has the class under 
**src->tests(package).**